# Have external php script output to block

Tags: magento2, php

I have a folder in magento root dir with a php script and want to run/output it in a block.
What code is needed to run the script in a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using include inside block's template.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code needed?

Comment: Inside .phtml: <?php include "path/to/external.php"; ?>